# Filter data frame by keyword list and string column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
Name     Street
Tom      125, Fullton Street
Bill     133, Brighton Street
Simon    152, Lampton Street
Angie    89,  Langdon Street
```

Now I want to keep only those rows that are part of a certain neighbourhood, by using a list of street names:

```
neighbours = [Fullton, Brighton]
```

I used this code, but it only keeps the row with Fullton street:

```
df_neighbours = df[df['Street'].str.contains(neighbours)]
```

Any idea? 
Thank you!

Comment: I would guess that you need to iterate over neighbors. I'd hazard that your code only accesses the the [0] index of neighbors for comparison.

Answer (score 4):

You are really close - need join with `|` for regex `or`:

```
df_neighbours = df[df['Street'].str.contains('|'.join(neighbours))]
```